# Propiedades en javascript

Tags: javascript

Buenas, estoy leyendo un libro (Eloquent javascript) y tengo un par de dudas sobre los objetos y las propiedades:

1- Los objetos solo pueden tener propiedades y no variables? me refiero a declararlas de la forma var b = 2

2- Las propiedades funcionan como una especie de diccionario? Me llama mucho la atención que se puedan llamar con los corchetes (como por ejemplo objeto[algo]). Otra cosa que me llama la atención es que el nombre de las propiedades pueda ser por ejemplo un string. Cuando agrego propiedades con la sintaxis objeto[algo]="sarasa" que estoy haciendo realmente?

Busque información sobre todo esto pero nada me dejo muy conforme, lo unico que habia programado antes es java y es como que busco una relación entre lo de js con este, agradecería si alguien puede responder mis dudas.

Saludos

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JavaScript, a diferencia de Java, no es un lenguaje tipado. Las funciones son ciudadanos de primera clase, y por lo tanto pueden aparecer en cualquier sitio donde apareciese un tipo básico. Esto implica que una función puede ser asociada a una variable, pasada como argumento, o retornada por otra función.

```
var foo = function() {
    return function(a, b) {
        return a+b;
    };
};
```

> Un objeto es una colección de propiedades, y una propiedad es una
>   asociación entre un nombre y un valor.

Las propiedades de un objeto pueden verse como variables ligadas a ese objeto. Por lo tanto una propiedad de un objeto puede contener un dato de cualquier tipo básico, arrays, otros objetos, o funciones (en cuyo caso reciben el nombre de métodos del objeto).

```
var obj = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    bar: function () {
        return this.a + this.b;
    },
    foo: function (a, b) {
        return a+b;
    }
};
```

Para acceder a las propiedades y métodos se utiliza una notación simple de puntos, o como comentas, entre corchetes.

```
obj.a;            // 1
obj['a'];         // 1
obj.bar();        // 3
obj['bar']();     // 3
obj.foo(3,4);     // 7
obj['foo'](3,4);  // 7
```

Cuando haces una asignación a una propiedad del objeto, por ejemplo `obj.c = 3` o `obj['c'] = 3` estás creando una propiedad del objeto `obj` asociada al nombre `c` con valor `3`, o modificando el valor de dicha propiedad si ya existía.

Comment: Entonces variables de la forma var b = 5  no puedo meter? Muchas gracias! Genial la explicación

Comment: No tal cual. Pero sí podrias declarar variables dentro de un método de un objeto: `var o = { foo: function() { var a = 5; return a; } };`.

Comment: Buenisimo! Aclaraste realmente todas mis dudas, la verdad js es muy diferente a programar en lenguajes mas tipados como java y al parecer tiene un concepto de objetos o una forma de escribir los mismos un poco diferente. Saludos