# ¿Porque es posible acceder a la posicion de un arreglo haciendo uso de una variable?

Tags: javascript

Estaba estudiando arreglos en JavaScript e estudie este ejemplo

```js
let array = [1,2,3,5,6];

for(let i=0; i<5; i++){
  console.log(array[i]);
}
```

Acceder al arreglo de esta manera es posible debido a que i es una variable y al usar la variable me estoy refiriendo al valor?, ¿hay algo que especifique concretamente el porque es posible usar una variable para referirme a la posición de un arreglo?
siempre que haga uso de una variable en un programa independientemente de la operación me estaré refiriendo al su valor como si el valor estuviese así en crudo por ejemplo i  = 0? Siempre me referiría al valor?

Comment: Declaras una variable i que tiene por valor 0 al iniciar el bucle for y que se incrementa en uno tras cada interacción, es por eso que puedes mostrar cada valor del array, porque muestras `array[0]` (0 es lo que vale i), después `array[1]` que es la segunda posición del array porque i ahora vale 1 y en la segunda posición de tu array tienes el 2.

También puedes usar otro método más efectivo para recorrer arrays especialmente cuando desconoces el numero de elementos que tiene o es un array bidimensional y sus índices no son numerales, me refiero al `foreach`, en js es el método `map`

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Acceder dinámicamente a una propiedad de un objeto usando una variable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/225783/acceder-din%c3%a1micamente-a-una-propiedad-de-un-objeto-usando-una-variable)

Answer (score 2):

Cuando llamas a una posición del array a través de `array[i]` estás llamando a la posición `i` del array.

Para que nos entendamos. Tu array ahora mismo podríamos interpretarlo de esta forma:

```
array[0] = 1;
array[1] = 2;
array[2] = 3;
array[3] = 5;
array[4] = 6;
```

Donde el número entre corchetes es la posición del array donde se guarda el valor de la derecha.

Ahora analicemos tu for:

en tu bucle for comienzas por dar un valor a la variable iteradora `i`, este valor coincide con la posición inicial del array (0), indicas que el bucle llegue hasta `i = 5`, que es, además, el tamaño total del array (array.length), y, por último, indicas que en cada iteración del bucle, se le sume 1 a la variable iteradora i (`i++`).

Con esto lo que etás haciendo es llamar repetidas veces a la posición `i` del array. Este valor `i` pasa por todos los valores desde `0` hasta `5`, así que estás llamando a las instrucciones:

```
console.log(array[0]); // valor de i = 0; resultado = 1
console.log(array[1]); // valor de i = 1; resultado = 2
console.log(array[2]); // valor de i = 2; resultado = 3
console.log(array[3]); // valor de i = 3; resultado = 5
console.log(array[4]); // valor de i = 4; resultado = 6
```

En respuesta a la segunda parte de tu pregunta. Mientras tu variable esté definida, podrás acceder a la posicion `array[myVariable]` de array si este array tiene una posición coincidente con el valor de `myVariable`, ya que se interpreta que `myVariable` toma el valor definido por ti.

Te dejo aquí un pequeño snippet para ilustrar lo que he mencionado anteriormente.

```js
const myArray = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6];

const myCustomIndex = 2;


// Valores de myArray[i] iterando sobre el array en un bucle for
for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i += 1) {
  console.log(`Este es el valor i = ${i} de myArray: ${myArray[i]}`)
}

// valor de miArray[myCustomIndex] cuando myCustomIndex está definido a 2

console.log(`Este es el valor myCustomIndex = ${myCustomIndex} de myArray: ${myArray[myCustomIndex]}`)
```

Comment: ¿Entonces cada vez que use una variable en la estructura de un programa, me estoy refiriendo al valor que contiene y en cualquier parte del programa que requiera de un valor puedo hacer uso de una variable porque esa es la utilidad de estas?

Comment: Eso dependerá del ámbito donde esté trabajando la variable. Ten en cuenta que no siempre vas a tener acceso a esa variable según dónde la declares. Por ejemplo, si es en una función, solo tendrás acceso en el ámbito de esa función. Si es una global, tendrás acceso desde cualquier parte, pero no te recomiendo hacerlo así.