# "@" me impide leer valor de propiedades de objeto recibido de procedimiento almacenado mysql

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, nodejs

-Trabajo con `javascript` en el front-end, `nodejs` en el back-end y `mysql`

-Realizo una petición get desde el front-end.

-En el backend:

-Llamo a un procedimiento almacenado de `mysql` que pose un parámetro out

-Consulto el valor de ese parámetro y lo envío al front end.

-Consulto el valor recibido en el front-end, obteniendo: `{@dato: 100}`

El "@" es imprescindible para obtener un parámetro de salida en procedimiento almacenado `mysql`.

El problema es que en, en el front-end no puedo consultar ese valor porque `javascript` no admite que las variables o nombres de atributos comiencen con "@"

¿Me podrían sugerir cómo solucionar esto o qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: es node el q arma el call y decide si responder con el row o un error, armate un ejemplo mínimo y vemos como transformar el response. si desde node mandas el result de mysql en crudo vas a recibir nombres de columnas en crudo ( asi como `SELECT @data;` en el client de mysql va a devolver una columna llamada `@data` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar prácticamente cualquier carácter si accedes de la manera adecuada:

```js
const values = { "@data": 100}

console.log(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2))

console.log("el valor de @data es", values["@data"])
```

Puedes ver más detalles [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/225783/acceder-din%C3%A1micamente-a-una-propiedad-de-un-objeto-usando-una-variable/225787#225787)

Puedes ahora elegir usar esa forma de acceder en el front o transformar el objecto en backend para usar otro nombre en el frontend.

Comment: Muchas gracias !! La sintaxis propuesta funcionó perfecto.

Comment: @Rafael Recuerda marcar las respuestas como aceptadas, tanto esta como las otras (obviamente si te solucionaron el problema). Saludos